# Reset ToggleButtons

Tags: vba, powerpoint, togglebutton

I am hoping to set all of the togglebuttons in a powerpoint to "false" (unpressed) upon starting the program. Any ideas why this sort of code is working?

```
Sub Start()
ActivePresentation.Slides(4).ToggleButton1.Value = 0
ActivePresentation.Slides(4).ToggleButton4.Value = 0

ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
```

End Sub

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(4).ToggleButton1.Value = 0
```

is correct; I've just tested it and it works.

Are you actually calling the Sub at any point though? Simply naming it Start() is not enough.

[Related question re. running code on startup, could be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964263/vba-powerpoint-auto-run-on-open-and-run-in-the-background)

Comment: I replied elsewhere that ToggleButton isn't a supported type.  You're correct, it is.  And I see that Matt's got the rest of the details worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue calling this

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(4).ToggleButton1.Value = 0
```

Getting the error `Method or data member not found` which im assuming is a scope issue. The VBA editor doesnt autocomplete `.ToggleButton1` which supports the error i was getting.
So, it appears im referencing the object incorrectly.

To correct this I have done the following.

```
Public Sub ToggleThisButton()
    ' This is code on Slide 1 referencing control on slide 4
    ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("ToggleButton1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1
End Sub
```

Excerpt from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223041(v=office.11).aspx)

> Use the OLEFormat property for a shape, inline shape, or field to
> return the OLEFormat object. The following example displays the class
> type for the first shape on the active document.
>
> Use the Object
> property to return an object that represents an ActiveX control or OLE
> object. With this object, you can use the properties and methods of
> the container application or the ActiveX control.